# JTextField and keyListener java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I'm try to add a keyListener to a JTextField (I want to parse the text each time I press a key), but the text is modified AFTER the keyListener is called...

Is there any way to change the text before parsing it?

Here is the code :

```
exampleTextField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
           String text = parsing(); //this method is called before te text is modified
           randomMethod(text);
       }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `keyReleased` or `keyTyped`?

Comment: @Braj this is the order from fastest to slowst: `pressed typed released`.

Comment: @ThriotgamesRiot what do you want to test? If the input is an Integer or something like that?

Comment: Yes I know it. Thanks.

Comment: @Braj KeyReleased would work, but it's not what I want in my context. KeyTyped doesn't work.

Comment: @KlemensMorbe The parsing method is just an example. I'm not only parsing it, I'm also calling other methods in the keyListener (the other methods are called each time I type a key, and this is what I want)

Comment: Please explain it in details. what are you doing in parsing? Just pass the value of `JTextField` in method `parsing`.

Comment: @Braj the problem is that the JTextField will keep it's old value, so if my JTextField had the value 'bob', and I type the letter 'a', the JTextField won't have the value 'boba' during my keyPressed, but 'bob', and when the method is finished, it will have the value 'boba'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a DocumentListener instead.

textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(...);

More info in the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html